# How to do Excel File upload in struts2?

Tags: file-upload, struts2

I am trying to upload Excel only file in Struts2 WEB Application. So using the following Code in Jsp page:

```
<s:label value="File Name : *" />
<s:file name="fileUpload" label="Select a File to upload"/>
<br>

<br>
<s:submit value="Add" name="add" tabindex="8" /> 



    </s:form>
```

In Response.jsp page displaying the File content and It's type as Follows:

```
   <s:form  action="saveBulkStores.action" method="get" >

<h4>
   File Name : <s:property value="fileUploadFileName"/> 
</h4> 

<h4>
   Content Type : <s:property value="fileUploadContentType"/> 
</h4> 

<h4>
   File : <s:property value="fileUpload"/> 
</h4> 

<br>
    </s:form>
```

In Struts.xml:

```
            <action name="bulkStores" class="com.action.FilesUploadAction"
        method="loadBulkStoresPage"> 
        <result name="input">/viewfile.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/uploadfile.jsp</result> 
    </action> 

            <action name="saveBulkStores" class="com.action.FilesUploadAction"
        method="saveBulkStores"> 
        <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="allowedTypes">text/plain</param>
            <param name="maximumSize">10240</param>
         </interceptor-ref> 
        <interceptor-ref name="params">
            <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="validation">
            <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
            <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
        </interceptor-ref> 
        <result name="input">/uploadfile.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result> 
    </action>
```

In Action Classes:

```
         public String loadBulkStoresPage(){
    System.out.println("FILES BULK UPLOADS.........");
    return SUCCESS;
     }
         private File fileUpload;
     private String fileUploadContentType; 
     private String fileUploadFileName;
         //Getters and Setters for above Fields.
```

Displaying filename,content type as follows:

```
         public String saveBulkStores(){
    System.out.println("check Bulk upload file");

    System.out.println("fileName:"+fileUploadFileName);
    System.out.println("content type:"+fileUploadContentType);
    System.out.println("fileupload:"+fileUpload); 

    return SUCCESS;
     }
```

Output:

```
   It's displaying NUll value only for my display statements. So anyone help me to fix this issue. thanks in Advance.
```

I am new to do this task.

Comment: Have you checked this struts file upload [docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/file-upload.html) yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FileUtils is not part of the standard JDK, it a class in the Apache Commons IO library.It contains Methods like

FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(source, destination);
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(source);......................which make copying files from one directory to other directory in most easier way in word it reduces voluminous amount of code as entire code is written by Apache people
please refer this URL for reference http://www.koders.com/java/fid002DB6BD79CABA7B6AA0F2669061424E3B9776D3.aspx
```

Comment: How do i get the uploading file's Real path?

Answer (score 0):

`<s:file id="myFile" name="myFile" disabled="true"  ></s:file>` is the tag that is used to upload file put the tag in jsp.

And the properties in action class as i written below

```
    private File myFile;
         private String myFileContentType;
         private String myFileFileName;

        /**
         * @return the myFile
         */
        public File getMyFile() {
            return myFile;
        }
        /**
         * @return the myFileContentType
         */
        public String getMyFileContentType() {
            return myFileContentType;
        }
        /**
         * @return the myFileFileName
         */
        public String getMyFileFileName() {
            return myFileFileName;
        }
        /**
         * @param myFile the myFile to set
         */
        public void setMyFile(File myFile) {
            this.myFile = myFile;
        }
        /**
         * @param myFileContentType the myFileContentType to set
         */
        public void setMyFileContentType(String myFileContentType) {
            this.myFileContentType = myFileContentType;
        }
        /**
         * @param myFileFileName the myFileFileName to set
         */
        public void setMyFileFileName(String myFileFileName) {
            this.myFileFileName = myFileFileName;
        }

and In execute method insert this code



      String destaddress=getText("ipaddress");
           if(myFile!=null){    
            File destDir= new File(destaddress+myFileFileName);
                    destDir.createNewFile();
                FileUtils.copyFile(myFile, destDir);
         }

you add ip address in apllication properties file as show below

ipaddress=\\\\192.168.105.68\\Shared2\\Files\\

and the following interceptors to your struts. XML file

    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                  <param name="maximumSize">52428800</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>

ipaddress=\\\\192.168.105.68\\Shared2\\Files\\
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks in Advance. I tried your code but getting following error message in Browser:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.struts2.interceptor.StrutsConversionErrorInterceptor.escape(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;                                                  I think the error is in File Object of my Class. So please help me.

Comment: This error occurs because you didn't set the form enctype type to “multipart/form-data”. http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-upload-multiple-files-example/